# ISY WLAN USB-Adapter IWL 1000 N150 not recognized

Tags: wireless, drivers

2 weeks ago, I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC. 
Everything is fine except from my wireless usb adapter. 
I have a ISY WLAN USB-Adapter IWL 1000 N150. I tried several ways to make it work but nothing. Probably i need a firmware - driver because it is not recognized from the operating system. 
Does anyone know how can i install drivers for this network adapter?
This is the first time working with Ubuntu for me, so I need a little bit of help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I've made a misstake, it must be

```
sudo modprobe r8712u
```

This is the appropiate kernel module.

I've also opened the ISY IWL 1000 adapter and a Belkin N150 F7D1101 v1 and it's exactly the same hardware.

Comment: So is this the correct modprobe for this device? We should fix the first answer instead!

Comment: Great news!!!
It works. Thank you very much.
The usb adapter is recognized but now it keeps asking me the password for the router. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this stick working, but driver quality seems to be poor, I got some disconnects here. 
To me it looks like the IWL 1000 is in fact a Belkin Components F7D1101 v1 Basic Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]. This device is supported by the r8712u kernel module. But the ISY IWL has a different device ID so the driver doesn't get loaded automatically. 
So you could assign the new ID to the kernel module:

```
echo 'install r8712u /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install r8712u; /bin/echo "050d 11f1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8712u.conf
```

after that see if it was successful:

```
sudo modprobe r8712u
iwconfig
dmesg | egrep 'rtl|wlan|Firm'
```

You should get something like this:

```
[ 2392.062628] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[ 2392.797877] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[ 2393.127647] udevd[2991]: renamed network interface wlan1 to wlan2
```

Comment: Hello, 
I tried your solution and I got 
"usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu" but again the adapter didn't work. 
The lsusb give me 050d:11f1 Belkin Components as a result.
According to [link](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) I have 11f2  ISY Wireless Micro Adapter IWL 2000 [RTL8188CUS]. 
I also tried to install the official drivers from Realteck but nothing again.